# SQL Server 2008 - Auditing Change Data Capture

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have been using SQL Server 2008 for about a year now and my knowledge is steadily progressing.

The nature of the data I work with is fairly sensitive and as a result I wanted to ensure the integrity of it by implementing an audit table. I successfully followed  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627397.aspx to guide me through the process and create my audit table.

So my question is in my log file there is a column called `Statement` which describes the action carried out i.e. Select/Update/Delete followed by the query ran. If I run a query with a where condition I don't get the value I inputted, i.e. `Where [Year] = 2010`, instead in my log file it is displayed as `Where [Year] = @Param1`

How can I get my file to display the value ran in the query?

Comment: I am using sql server 2005 with Express Edition. can we do it in this version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to use triggers to do that so you have access to the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables. I use a modified version of this article in my own projects:

[Adding simple trigger-based auditing to your SQL Server database](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/27/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to implement the trigger on my test table and it works great.