# SQL Server 2008 - Trigger not reading column names with spaces

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I have been using SQL Server 2008 for about a year now and my knowledge is steadily progressing.

Recently I asked a question on how to implement and audit table on the database I am using in SQL Server 2008. I was successfully able to deploy triggers on a test table following the advice from my previous question [SQL Server 2008 - Auditing Change Data Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273754/sql-server-2008-auditing-change-data-capture)

In the database I am using during it's design stage (before my time) some condoned principals were applied which included creating tables and column names with spaces in the title. As a result I have noticed that this causes a problem when setting a trigger on a table that has these characteristics.

So my question is how do I in my trigger script allow for spaces on the table and column names without re designing all the tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to your table (or columns) like this:

```
[table name]
```

Use the square brackets.